# Identifying in which column(s) value changes in R data.frame for two sequencing rows in r software

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, key-value, set-difference

I have a data frame in R with a column that contains an ID for each row/record. A lot of the ID's do appear twice. These records (row) are almost similar, with minor differences in a column, for example two different birthdates for one ID.
So one of these row should be kept. Now I want to identify the columns with these differences without looping.

[This is the database][1]

```
structure(list(Idnumber = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L
), gender = c("M", "V", "V", "V", "V", "V", "M", "M", "V"), birthdate = 
c("10/2/2010", "10/2/2010", "12/12/2009", "12/13/2009", "1/30/2010", 
"1/30/2010", "5/5/2009", "5/5/2009", "5/5/2009"), Name = c("Henry", 
"Henry", "Varry", "Varry", "Lorsi", "Lorsi", "Dan", "Dam", "Dan"), 
Registerdate = c("1/10/2021", "1/10/2021", "1/11/2021", "1/11/2021", 
"1/10/2021", "1/11/2021", "1/10/2021", "1/10/2021", "1/10/2021")
```

The output I want is something like this:
check = c("", "gender", "", "bithdate", "", "registerdate", "", "Name",
"geslacht, Name"))

Uptill now I found these code:

```
for (i in 1:r)
{

if (dataSorted[i+1,1]==dataSorted[i,1]){

d=setdiff(dataSorted[i+1,],dataSorted[i,])
checkpoints=names(d)

#merge the names from checkpoints in one cel
Check=apply(t(checkpoints),1,paste,collapse="-")
Check=as.data.frame(matrix(Check))
class(Check)

#save these Checkpoint a next column
dataSorted[i+1,k+1]=Check[1,1]
}}
```

Can someone help me to improve it?
What is the V-8 I am getting in the output? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Would you please share a reproducible part of your data so that we can work on it.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? I.e. what is a "minor" difference? Does this mean at most one column is different?

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I hope the example can be read now. With minor changes I mean that there could be a difference in the way a name is spelled, of a slide difference in birthdate, of that we have missing data in one of the rows. Sometime the difference could be in more than one column.